# Opening Credit Card Tab by default using PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-express

We are using PayPal Express checkout on our client's website.

We have to open the credit-card tab on paypal's website by default instead of paypal account tab as shown below.

[image]

Now i checked the Query String passed in the URL. When clicked on cc it appends the parameter `pageSate=billing` and then it populates the CC field in credit card form.

I want this to happen by default. I checked into admin but there is no option for it.

Is there any way i can do this by modifying the code for PayPal in Magento ?

Can anyone guide me through this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last i was able to figure out how to do it. Thought to share the answer so someone like me can save the time and spend it for some fruitful purpose :P

So, what i did was

1) I checked for PayPal's API Calls from developer profile. The link for it is [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

To open the credit card option by default you need to pass the API with parameters `LANDINGPAGE=Billing`.

2) Searched for API calls in Magento for PayPal and found the file `Nvp.php` at app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php

3)  Search for the function `callSetExpressCheckout()` after `$this->_exportLineItems($request);` enter the following line `$request['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Billing';`

This is all. Now test it using Express Checkout. I haven't yet tested it thorougly. Please add up to the answer if there are any better suggestion for it.

Comment: Do you know where to add $request['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Billing'; for Paypal Payment standard method in 1.7.0.2

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work with standard PayPal.. PayPal allows it only for express checkout..

Comment: Partially OT - is there a way to specify the LANDINGPAGE parameter using the PayPal REST API?